# I need to console log my anser and not just return it

Tags: javascript

I need to console log my anser and not just return it

I have tried this however in my console it does not LOG it but returns (3) ["JavaScript", "CSS", "HTML"] 
I need it to return
* HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT

```
function logReverse(input) {
    let arr = input.reverse();
    console.log(arr) 

}
//test
logReverse(['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'])
```

Please  help out

Comment: currently, you are just logging, not returning

Comment: Be careful when using the "return" word, showing in screen isn't really returning. BTW, maybe you are looking for logging using foreach? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I see it logging and not returning the array. Running the code should clearly have `(3) ["JavaScript", "CSS", "HTML"]` in the developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run code in the console, return values are displayed as well as any console output. What you should see in the console when you run that code is:

1. `Array(3) [ "JavaScript", "CSS", "HTML" ]` - this is the `console.log`, logging the object you have passed it
2. `undefined` - this is the return value of the function

When you said you need it to return `HTML,CSS,JavaScript`, I assume what you actually want to do is to take a string value of the reversed array, which would look like this:

```js
console.log(Array(...input).reverse().toString())
```

Note that I've wrapped the input in `Array(...input)`, which creates a new array. `Array.prototype.reverse` will reverse the array in place, which means that it changes the value of reverse. By making a new array, you can avoid modifying the input.

The call to `Array.prototype.toString` will join the elements with commas, which I believe is the desired effect you're after.